# Characterize those non-empty graphs with the property that every two distinct maximal independent set of vertices are disjoint

Tags: graph-theory

> > An independent set of vertices in a graph $G$ is **maximal independent** if $S$ is not a proper subset of any other independent set of vertices in $G$.

Characterize those non-empty graphs with the property that every two distinct maximal independent set of vertices are disjoint

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but independent set is a set of vertices such that non of them are adjacent to each other, and we are looking at the maximal indepeendt set of vertices.

I'm not sure about how they want me "characterize". But I guess for a bipartite, you can find 2 distinct maximal independent set that are disjoint.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, and help me understand this better.

Comment: One example is a cycle of even length.  What other examples can you come up with?

Comment: is the complement of $K_k$ where $k$ is even work?

Comment: Assume $K_k$ denotes the complete graph?  I think $K_k$ itself works-- the maximal independent sets only have one element, so they're all disjoint.  The complement of $K_k$ has no edges, so there's only one maximal independent set -- I suppose the condition holds vacuously for such graphs.

Comment: so the cubic graphs are also work.By saying characterize, they just want me to give a bunch of example like that ?

Comment: No. If you had a list of examples, and you could prove that *every* $G$ was accounted for in your list, then, yes, that would count as a characterization. Another approach would be to show that a graph has this property if and only if it has some other set of properties, but again you need to prove your answer. In any case, a good thing to do when confronted with such a question is to start by listing some examples, and seeing what they have in common.  (Actually the even cycle example is wrong. -- sorry..)

Comment: Cubic graphs don't work in general.  For the 8 vertices of a cube, there are $2$ disjoint $4$-element independent sets, but the pair of diagonally opposite vertices is independent, and intersects both of the $4$-element sets.  The answer Brian Scott sketches is right.

Comment: a characterization is essentially an if and only if statement.  Thus a characterization of, say, eulerian graphs would be that an eulerian graph is a graph in which the degree of every vertex is even.  A graph, G, is eulerian IFF every vertex of G has even degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that maximal independent sets of vertices of $G=\langle V,E\rangle$ are pairwise disjoint. Define a relation $\sim$ on $V$ by $u\sim v$ iff $\{u,v\}$ is independent.

- Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $V$.
- Show that for all $u,v\in V$, $uv$ is an edge of $G$ iff $u\not\sim v$.
- Show that if $\{V_1,\ldots,V_n\}$ is the set of $\sim$-equivalence classes, then $\{V_1,\ldots,V_n\}$ is a partition of $V$ into maximal independent sets, and $G$ is the complete $n$-partite graph with parts $V_1,\ldots,V_n$.